existence of subsequence in unit ball in Hilbert space
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $(x_n)_n$ a sequence in the unit ball.
(a) Prove there exists a subsequence $n_j$ such that
$$\lim_{j \to \infty}\langle x_{n_j},y \rangle$$
exists for al $y \in H$.
(b) Prove there exists $x \in B$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle = \lim_{j \to \infty} \langle x_{n_j},y \rangle$ for all $y \in H$.
Attempt:
First suppose $y \in M = \overline{\text{span}(x_n)_n}$. Note
$$b_n:= \langle x_n,y \rangle$$
is a sequence of reals. And
\begin{align*}
    \vert b_n \vert &=\vert \langle x_n, y \rangle \vert\\
    &\leq \vert \vert x_n \vert \vert \vert \vert y \vert \vert && \text{triangle inequality}\\
    &\leq \vert \vert y \vert \vert && \text{as $x_n \in B$} \\
    &\leq \sum_{k=1}^N \vert \vert a_k \vert \vert && \text{as $y$ is in the span}\\
    &< \infty && \text{finite combo of numbers from field is finite}.
\end{align*}
Thus $b_n$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers so there exists a convergent subsequence, say $n_j$ so that
$$\lim_{j \to \infty} b_{n_j}=\lim_{j \to \infty}\langle x_{n_j}, y \rangle$$
exists. Next assume $y \in H = M \oplus M^\perp$, then $y=a+b$ for $a \in M, b \in M^\perp$. Then
\begin{align*}
    \langle x_n, y \rangle&=\langle x_n, a+b \rangle\\
    &=\langle x_n, a \rangle && \text{since $b \in M^\perp$}.
\end{align*}
We used that $\langle x_n, b \rangle = 0$ since $b \in M^\perp$, and as $a \in M$, and we showed the subsequence exists for all $y \in M$, we are done.
Is this correct?
For (b) how do I show the subseqeucne covnerges to some $x \in B$.

The question asks for a single subsequence $n_j$ that is valid for all $y$, whereas you only proved that for each $y$ there is a subsequence $n_j$. The subsequence could very much depends on $y$, so this is not correct.

Hint: $\overline{\mathrm{span}(x_n)_n}$ is separable, so you may choose a dense sequence $(y_j)_j$. Now do a diagonalization trick.

Let $f(y)=\lim \langle x_{n_j}, y \rangle$. Thene $f$ is a linear functional and $|f(y)|\leq \lim \sup \|x_{n_j}\|\|y\|\leq \|y\|$, so $f$ is a continuous linear functional. By Riesz Theorem there exists $x \in H$ such that  $\lim \langle x_{n_j}, y \rangle =f(y)= \langle x, y \rangle$ for all $y$.
